# How do I check if the title has a strikethrough in Reddit submission?

Tags: python, python-3.x, reddit, praw

First off I'm using PRAW Api for reddit. Im trying to eliminate some of the posts I saved from reddit. These will be the ones that have a ~~strikethrough~~. Im working on a bot that saves all the free, PC games to a txt file on my desktop.

Possible title would look like this: <strike>[Origin] Need for Speed: Most Wanted (FREE/-100%)</strike> on reddit. 
See this [reddit post](https://se.reddit.com/r/GameDeals/comments/43vdvu/origin_need_for_speed_most_wanted_free100/)

I am able to iterate over the new submissions like this:

```
subreddit = r.get_subreddit("GameDeals")           
submissions = subreddit.get_new(limit = 100)

for each in submissions: 
    if "100" in each.title or "free" in each.title:
        ...do stuff...
```

I want to add a check to see if each. Title has a strikethrough it.

I tried:

```
if each.strikethrough:
    ...do stuff...
```

and others like linethrough... I cant get it to work. and there doesn't seem to be any help under PRAW documentations

Comment: Strikethrough can't be used in titles of Reddit posts. This must be the work of CSS.

Answer (score 1):

So /r/Gamedeals repurposes the NSFW toggle and uses CSS to inject a "Deal Expired" button, along with a strikethrough on the title.
Just looked at the JSON for the page and NSFW is set by `"over_18": true` or `"over_18": false`. You can get this through the `over_18` attribute in PRAW.

```
import praw

r = praw.Reddit(user_agent='over18 by /u/cdcformatc')
subreddit = r.get_subreddit("GameDeals")
submissions = subreddit.get_new(limit = 100)

for s in submissions:
    print(s.over_18)
```